# How do I combine a substring and trim right in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I am trying to extract the data between two underscore characters. In some situations, the 2nd underscore may not exist.

```
MyFld
P_36840
U_216137
C_203134_H
C_203134_W
```

I tried this:

```
substring(i.[MyFld],
      CHARINDEX ('_',i.[MyFld])+1,len(i.[MyFld])
     -CHARINDEX ('_',i.[MyFld])
) [DerivedPrimaryKey]
```

And I get this:

```
DerivedPrimaryKey
36840
216137
203134_H
203134_W
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/uPKC6oX4

I want to remove the second underscore and data that follows it. I'm trying to combine it with a trim right, but I'm unsure where to start.

How can I do this?

Comment: The square brackets imply SQL Server. Is this correct?

Comment: SQL database are not meant for string manipulation. The code for this is gonna get kind of a ugly. You may find you do MUCH better extracting the value in the client code or reporting tool, or (even better) adding a separate column for it to set at INSERT/UPDATE time.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server. 
Yes, this gets very ugly in string manipulation, but it is what it is.
I am trying to extract portion of this column to do comparisons against a key field for reporting.

Answer (score 3):

We can start by simplifying what you have so far. I will also add enough to make this a complete query, so we can see it in context for later steps:

```
SELECT 
   right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld)) [DerivedPrimaryKey]
FROM I
```

With this much done, we can now use it as the source for removing the trailing portion of the field:

```
SELECT 
   reverse(substring(reverse(step1)
      , charindex('_', reverse(step1))+1
      , len(step1)
  )) [DerivedPrimaryKey]
FROM (
    SELECT right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld)) [step1]
    FROM I
) T
```

Notice the layer of nesting. You can, of course, remove the nesting, but it means replicating the entire inner expression every time you see `step1` (good thing I took the time to simplify it):

```
SELECT 
   reverse(substring(reverse(right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld)))
      , charindex('_', reverse(right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld))))+1
      , len(right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld)))
  ))
FROM I
```

And now back to just the expression:

```
reverse(substring(reverse(right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld)))
      , charindex('_', reverse(right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld))))+1
      , len(right(i.MyFld, len(i.MyFld) - charindex('_', i.MyFld)))
  ))
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/nFO4Vwhm

There is also this alternate expression that saves one function call:

```
left(   right(i.MyFld,len(i.MyFld)-charindex('_',i.MyFld)), 
   coalesce(
      nullif(
        charindex('_', 
            right(i.MyFld,len(i.MyFld)-charindex('_',i.MyFld)) 
         ) -1, -1,
      ), 
      len( right(i.MyFld,len(i.MyFld)-charindex('_',i.MyFld)) )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a two more options.   One using parsename() provided your data does not  have more than 4 segments.  The second using a JSON array

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([MyFld] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('P_36840')
,('U_216137')
,('C_203134_H')
,('C_203134_W')
 
Select *
      ,UsingParseName = reverse(parsename(reverse(replace(MyFld,'_','.')),2))
      ,UsingJSONValue = json_value('["'+replace(MyFld,'_','","')+'"]','$[1]')
 From  @You
```

**Results**

```
MyFld       UsingParseName  UsingJSONValue
P_36840     36840           36840
U_216137    216137          216137
C_203134_H  203134          203134
C_203134_W  203134          203134
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the ParseName() idea. Definitely not what it's intended for, but it'll sure simplify this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  Just risky if more than 4 segments.   I tend to lean towards the JSON approach.   It just may require a string_escape( ... ,'json')

Comment: I have a nearly-automatic negative response to seeing JSON in a db. Too many times seeing someone expect to parse values out for something like a WHERE clause comparison without realizing it meant they couldn't use the expected index and it would do the full parsing work on that column for every row in a table, even if they only expect to match on a few of them. So I don't like giving people hints there might be more JSON support than they realize ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I get your concerns, however, in my view it is just another tool in the belt.  Like you, over the years I've had to import and process some horrible data, and this is just a means to an end.

Answer (score 1):

Often I try to fake out SQL if an expected character isn't always present and I don't need the resulting value:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field_Calculated, 1, CHARINDEX('_', field_Calculated) - 1)  
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(MyFld, CHARINDEX('_', MyFld) + 1, LEN(MyFld)) + '_' As field_Calculated 
  FROM MyTable) T
```

I think this is clear, but I really like the ParseName solution @JohnCappalletti suggests.

If it's only ever one numeric value you can use string_split:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY string_split(MyFld, '_')
WHERE ISNUMERIC(value) = 1
```

Either way you have to be careful of the data before deciding the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this:

```
Declare @testData Table ([MyFld] varchar(50));
 Insert Into @testData (MyFld)
 Values ('P_36840')
      , ('U_216137')
      , ('C_203134_H')
      , ('C_203134_W');
 
 Select *
      , second_element = substring(v.MyFld, p1.pos, p2.pos - p1.pos - 1)
   From @testData                                               As td
  Cross Apply (Values (concat(td.MyFld, '__')))                 As v(MyFld)  -- Make sure we have at least 2 delimiters
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('_', v.MyFld, 1) + 1))         As p1(pos)   -- First Position
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('_', v.MyFld, p1.pos) + 1))    As p2(pos)   -- Second Position
```

If you actually have a fixed number of characters in the first element, then it could be simplified to:

```
 Select *
      , second_element = substring(v.MyFld, 3, charindex('_', v.MyFld, 4) - 3)
   From @testData td
  Cross Apply (Values (concat(td.MyFld, '_'))) As v(MyFld)
```

Answer (score -1):

your data

```
Declare @Table Table ([MyFld] varchar(100))  
Insert Into @Table
([MyFld] ) Values 
('P_36840')
,('U_216137')
,('C_203134_H')
,('C_203134_W')
```

use `SubString`,`Left` and `PatIndex`

```
select 
  Left(
    SubString(
      [MyFld], 
      PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [MyFld]), 
      8000
    ), 
    PatIndex(
      '%[^0-9.-]%', 
      SubString(
        [MyFld], 
        PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [MyFld]), 
        8000
      ) + 'X'
    )-1
  )  as DerivedPrimaryKey
from 
  @Table
```